# ASP.NET AJAX Doesnt Work

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a very simple AJAX example that doesn't work.
It is from the Microsoft tutorials on AJAX.

When I click on button "Button1" AJAX should execute but the whole page submits.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="1111.aspx.cs" Inherits="_1111" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>  
</head>    
<body>    
  <form id="form1" runat="server">    
  <p>    
    DropDownList AutoPostBack SelectedIndexChanged EventArgs Sort ... Since you will    
    be using AJAX to process your SelectedIndexChanged event, set the AutoPostBack property    
    of the DropDownList to false. ...</p>    
  <div>       

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">    
    </asp:ScriptManager>    
    <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />   
    <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />    
    <center>    
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">    
      <ContentTemplate>    
        <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>    
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button 1" />    
      </ContentTemplate>    
      <Triggers>    
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />    
      </Triggers>    
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </center>    
  </div>    
  </form>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Web;    
using System.Web.UI;    
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    

public partial class _1111 : System.Web.UI.Page    
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {    
        label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();    
        label2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();    
        label3.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();    
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Not wanting to be a nitpicky language nazi type, but your title is very wrong.  Asp.Net AJAX very much works, as millions of developers make use of it daily.  More specifically your install of ASP.net AJAX doesn't work, but even that may be false, as it could be a misconfigured server, a coding error, a browser with scripting disabled, or any other number of things that cause the problem.  A *much* better title would have been, "ASP.NET AJAX code is still causing full postback" for example.

Comment: Are you getting a javascript error of any sort?

Comment: justed pasted your code into an asp.net ajax project in VS2008 and it does callbacks not postbacks, i.e., works as expected

Comment: It was a silly web.config error as noted below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works for me. 
The reason is possibly you are not configuring your web.config file properly. See what is inside your file.

It needs some components to support MS AJAX Extensions.

Go to

http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-add-aspnet-ajax-features-to-an-existing-web-application.

Have a look at the tutorial to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstanding is in the Page_Load event, which will always fire, even for partial post-backs. You can handle that by making any initialization code conditional, as in:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();    
    label2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();    
    label3.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();    
}
```